# Iterate unordered set that change size during cicle C++

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, cycle, unordered-set

I'm trying to iterate an unordered_set by a for-cycle.
The problem occour because in this cycle can happen that an element or more elements are added into the container that I'm iterating.

I need to iterate until the last element (including elements added during for cicle)

Using unorderd_set I'm iterating in this way:

```
std::unordered_set<T> mySet;
for (auto itr = mySet.begin(); itr != mySet.end(); ++itr) {
    mySet.insert(someInt);
    /* ...*/
}
```

In this way the iteration will stop at the size that the unordered_set have had at the start of the iteration. So it doesn't see that the size is changed.

This dipendent iteration is what I need. I'm going to work with unordered_set to have better performance adding elelement and searching it inside myContainer. Without this dipendendt cycle I can't replace the vector with the unordered_set.

Thank's

Comment: "This dipendent iteration is what I need." -> [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need it? sets are no sequence container. Already iterating from begin till end is a (minor) code smell. Please explain what is the actual problem you want to solve. What is `/*..something happens..*/` and `/*.......*/` ?

Comment: Modification of any container while concurrently iterating it is always a bad idea when no due care is taken. In this concrete case `itr` becomes invalid as noted here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert

Comment: `If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not invalidated.`

Comment: I need to replicate, if possible, the for-cicle as shown in the vector case. In the for-cicle could be possibile that an element or more elements are added to the container. With vector I have no problem to do this. With unordered_set I've problem.
The question is if is there a way to do this with unordered_set.

Comment: The inherit problem is that your iterators can become invalidated when you insert something in the set. You first need to determine which elements you want to insert by e.g storing them in a temporary `std::vector` and then insert them in one go. Maybe `std::unordered_set` is not the right datatype for this but thats something we probably cant answer because that would require us to have indepth knowledge of the problem at hand.

Comment: The solution to this problem is very likely to split the task into multiple steps instead of trying to solve it all at once in a single loop. But thats just speculation

Comment: When you eventually come around to creating a [mcve], please include enough to reveal the true nature of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You will have the exact same problem if you use a `vector`. Inserting into a vector while iterating invalidates iterators, so after an insert you can't continue the for-loop. The fact that it appears to work sometimes doesn't mean that it's correct. You can't modify any collection while iterating it.

Comment: @rustyx if I know the max value of item that vector can reach I use reserve function so the vector reallocate space and iterator isn't invalided. Correct me if I'm wrong